# Who sets the rules of society(*), and shapes the choices (we) make?

Tags: free-will

Free will as a concept implies that someone can act following set rules, or make other choices (breaking laws is included). But who sets legal choices? Society? Or society in dialog with individuals? Or what is the principle?

If free will doesn't exist, who will set the rules and choices, or what will they be? Can someone represent mechanisms, how it will work if we are without free will?

(*) I didn't write "society" because society can be only in free will concept with laws set up - "contract" between society and people (?). If you have no individual or person "free will" the contract can't exist. And you have no society too. For example society before the liberty contract (but with people) calls "traditional society". TS ≠ S (also TS⊄S (it can be discussing a long...)), but FW = ø => S'≠ S at least.

Who are the people, what is the society'(S') without free will and who will set the rules of the New world (in theory)?

Comment: See e.g. [The Rule of Law](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rule-of-law/): "The Rule of Law comprises a number of principles of a formal and procedural character, addressing the way in which a community is governed." There are laws that govern the society: laws are set and maintained by appropriate institutions. NO dialog with individuals.

Comment: Thank you, but who set them and what is a principle of second/who set it ( in probably or in theory)?

Comment: Who set laws? It depends: in modern democracies the Parliament. In [Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghanistan#Second_Taliban_era_(2021%E2%80%93present)) the [Mullah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibatullah_Akhundzada).

Comment: Is Parliament consists of persons? Mullah is interesting, but (Afghanistan is not a center of "free will", liberty and else) lets concentrate on main.

Comment: [Social contract theorists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_contract) assert that people enter a "social contract" in order to limit their freedom in exchange for some benefits that can be implemented at a social level.

Comment: who are/is people?

Comment: Modern democracies are grounded on the so-called [Separation of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_powers) principle commonly ascribed to Baron de Montesquieu's [The Spirit of Laws (*De l'esprit des loix*, 1748)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spirit_of_Law).

Comment: Study an ant colony for a while. Kids used to do that... Now I suppose they look at Twitter instead. Same thing.

Comment: @Scott Rowe so, you think kids do? i liked to play with ants when i was a kid. i put my hand on the forest ants nest and they colonized it. But there is no forest and forest ants today, my kids can't play with ants. concrete+glass+plastic with society glue - that is my jungles, flat is my nest, i become an ant myself, motioning by emotion's pheromones. But if im not an ant who am i? And i still remember that im not an ant, but my kids didn't know how to be not an ants. Who are they?

Comment: Thank you, Mauro, but i don't think that any laws have the Spirit. Laws it is instructions(or rules) to lowering the accidents and conflicts. Laws are not the Spirit of the God dead or alive nvm. They are society game rules not more not less.
Also i asked the question about the Goddess of Liberty, but it was deleted, so i think the Spirit of Laws is not actually exists.

Comment: Philosophers like [Foucault](https://www.powercube.net/other-forms-of-power/foucault-power-is-everywhere/), and to some extent Marx, have focused on power structures and power relations within groups and society. These power structures may form laws and rules as well. You may be interested in that.

Answer (score 2):

From the clarificatory footnote, I think this question means to ask about Rousseau's account of the "general will" in relation to both the "social contract" theory, and the "free will" of individuals. The question supposes that if there is no free will, then there can be no social contract and hence no society. At least, there might be people going through the motions of having a society, such as producing texts called "laws" and people called "judges", but we may not be justified in calling this a "society" since it consists entirely of automatons who have not in fact consented to be governed, since they can't consent to anything.

While the idea of social contract has been explored by many authors, the formulation involving the collective will of society as a whole is strongly associated with Jean-Jacques Rousseau and his work *The Social Contract* (1762). He supposes that people (who have free will) choose to identify as citizens of a society, and undertake to conform the choices they make in life to the "will" of that society. That "will" can be in the form of law, i.e. established rules of conduct. It would be nice if the laws were such that there was no tension between individual will, and what society collectively wills,  but this does not always happen. Sometimes, people will want to do things that law forbids, and they might even break the law(!). It would also be nice if the laws comported with some notion of natural justice or ethics, but that cannot be guaranteed. But to some extent, we can say that there is a social contract in play insofar as citizens agree to be bound by the general will, and will comply with a law because their respect for the law and society as a whole is greater than their desire to break it.

A different view of social contract comes from Thomas Hobbes. Rather than saying that people idealistically subordinate themselves to the general will, he thinks that pure self-interest is enough to explain both the forms of society, and to provide a moral obligation to remain subject to its rules. If laws are being made by a tyrant who is nonetheless quite good at his job in terms of giving you a nice life, you have reason to obey his laws. On the contrary, Rousseau's theory sees such a society as illegitimate because the tyrant cannot be truly representing the general will (there are no mechanisms for aggregating individual free will and discerning what people want), and if the general will isn't present then citizens can't choose to agree with it.

Crucially, Hobbes himself takes a very low view of free will. He believes that while we can talk about "volition", this is so bounded by circumstances and human fallibility that it cannot rise to the level that Free Will proponents need it to have. People act according to their interests, but Will is not a transcendent thing that has any power beyond the choices that individuals make. In particular, philosophers in the line of Hobbes would reject the idea of "general will" or "the will of society" as an incoherent concept. They may still think there is such a thing *as* society, and even that there is a social contract which obliges citizens to obey its laws, but they do not found this concept on individual free will.

Suppose we take an even more deterministic view. If I am a citizen of the automaton-society of the first paragraph above, then per Rousseau there is no social contract at all. In a Hobbesian view, it is simply irrelevant whether the laws are produced by agents having free will, or not. If they are good for me to follow then I will follow them, and if the automaton-society defends my interests then I have an unfolding duty to continue to do so. There can still be a "social contract" because my obligation towards the sovereign is not dependent on whether its choices are freely willed. If I myself do not have free will either, I may still have moral obligations of this kind (at least, there are determinists who believe this).